# What's the difference between raw types, unbounded wild cards and using Object in generics

Tags: java, generics, effective-java

I am reading the chapter on Generics in Effective Java.

Help me understand difference between `Set`, `Set<?>` and `Set<Object>`?

The following paragraph is taken from the book.

> As a quick review, `Set<Object>` is a parameterized type representing a
>   set   that can contain objects of any type, `Set<?>` is a wildcard type
>   representing  a set that can contain only objects of some unknown
>   type, and `Set` is a raw type, which opts out of the generic type
>   system.

What is meant by "some unknown type"? Are all unknown types of type `Object`? In that case what is the specific difference between `Set<?>` and `Set<Object>`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

- a raw type (`Set`) treats the type as if it had *no generic type information at all*. Note the subtle effect that not only will the type argument `T` be ignored, but also all other type arguments that methods of that type might have. You can add any value to it and it will always return `Object`.
- `Set<Object>` is a `Set` that accepts all `Object` objects (i.e. *all* objects) and will return objects of type `Object`.
- `Set<?>` is a `Set` that accepts all objects of *some specific, but unknown* type and will return objects of that type. Since *nothing* is known about this type, you can't *add* anything to that set (except for `null`) and the only thing that you know about the values it returns is that they are some sub-type of `Object`.

Comment: So is a raw type (`set`) the same as a set that accepts `Object` types (`Set <Object>`)?

Comment: @orrymr: it will work very similarly, but it's explicitly not assignment-compatible (and some corner-cases are actually different). Also, technically it's not always `Object`, but the lower bound of the generic type (i.e. if the generic type is just `<T>`, then it's `Object`, but if the generic type is `<T extends Number>` then the lower bound is `Number`).

Comment: Not assignment compatible, so you couldn't say:
`Set <Object> mySet = new Set <Integer>;`  ?
Would this be because `Set <Integer>` does _not_ inherit from `Set <Object>`?

Answer (score 3):

At runtime, the JVM will just see `Set` because of type erasure.

At compile-time, there's a difference:

`Set<Object>` parameterized a type `E` with `Object` thus, `Set.add(E element)` will be parameterized to `Set.add(Object element)`.

`Set<?>` on the other hand, adds a wildcard on a type `E` so `Set.add(E element)` is translated to `Set.add(? element)`. Since this is not compilable, java instead "translates" it as `Set.add(null element)`. It means that you cannot add anything to that set (except a null). The reason is that the wildcard is referencing to an unknown type.

Comment: Though Set<Object>, is parameterized to Set.add(Object element), it is not possible to add a sub type of Object(eg. String) right ?

Comment: It is possible since **all concrete** classes implicitly/explicitly extends `Object`.

Comment: So why does this code not compile ?Set<Object> set = new HashSet<Integer>();

Comment: Because you have instantiated your set wrong. The instance `set` must have the **same type** `T` of which you assigned. The correct thing is to do `Set<Object> set = new HashSet<Object>();`. Yours can be interpreted as `Set<T> set = new HashSet<U>()` (`T` != `U` in Generics term).

Answer (score 3):

> what is meant by "some unknown type"

Exactly what it means - the `Set` has *some* generic parameter, but we don't know what it is.

So the set assigned to a `Set<?>` variable might be a `Set<String>`, or a `Set<Integer>`, or a `Set<Map<Integer, Employee>>` or a set containing any other specific type.

So what does that mean for how you can use it?  Well, anything you get out of it will be an instance of the `?`, whatever that is.  Since we don't know what the type parameter is, you can't say anything more specific than that elements of the set will be assignable to `Object` (only because all classes extend from it).

And if you're thinking of adding something to the set - well, the `add` method takes a `?` (which makes sense, since this is the type of objects within the set).  But if you try to add any specific object, how can you be sure this is type-safe?  You can't - if you're inserting a String, you might be putting it into a `Set<Integer>` for example, which would break the type-safety you get from generics.  So while you don't know the type of the generic parameter, you can't supply any arguments of this type (with the single exception of `null`, as that's an "instance" of any type).

---

As with most generics-related answers, this has focused on collections because they're easier to comprehend instinctively.  However the arguments apply to any class that takes generic parameters - if it's declared with the unbounded wildcard parameter `?`, you can't *supply* any arguments to it, and any values you *receive* of that type will only be assignable to `Object`.

Answer (score 2):

`Set`: No generics here, unsafe. Add what you want.

`Set<?>`: A set of a certain type we don't know from our scope. The same as `Set<? extends Object>`. Can reference to Sets of any type, but that type must be defined at the point where the set is actually instantiated. With the wildcarded reference, we can´t modify the set (we can't add or remove with anything not null). Is like a view.

`Set<Object>`: Set containing Objects (base class only, not subclasses). I mean you can instance the set using Collections of type Object, like `HashSet<Object>` but not with `HashSet<String>`. You can of course add elements of any type to the set, but just because it happens that everything is an Object or a subclass of Object. If the set were defined as Set, you can only add Numbers and subclasses of Number, and nothing more.

Comment: A `Set<Object>` can *definitely* contain any subclass of `Object`, you can add `Integer`, `String` and everything else to it.

Comment: So why does this code not compile ?Set<Object> set = new HashSet<Integer>()

Comment: @cmv Because you are defining the set reference as a Set of type Object and nothing more. You should have written `Set<? extends Object>` in order to compile. Notice that it is possible to write `Object[] arr = new Integer[3];` with arrays.

Comment: @cmv the reason the compiler prevents you from assigning `HashSet<Integer>` to `Set<Object>` or even `HashSet<Object>` is because holding that reference you would add something that is not an Integer.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between `Set<Object>` and `Set<?>` is that a variable of type `Set<?>` can have a more specific generic type assigned to it, as in:

```
Set<?> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
```

while `Set<Object>` can only be assigned `Set<Object>`:

```
Set<Object> set = new HashSet<Integer>(); // won't compile
```

The `Set<Object>` is still useful, since any object can be put into it. It is much like the raw `Set` in that sense, but works better with the generic type system.

Answer (score 1):

```
Set<?> set = new HashSet<String>();
set.add(new Object()); // compile time error
```

Since we don’t know what the element type of set stands for, we cannot add objects
to it. The `add()` method takes arguments of type `E`, the element type of the `Set`.
When the actual type parameter is `?`, it stands for some unknown type. Any 
parameter we pass to add would have to be a subtype of this unknown type. Since we 
don’t know what type that is, we cannot pass anything in. The sole exception is 
`null`, which is a member of every type.

Given a `Set<?>`, we can call `get()` and make use of the result. The result type is an
unknown type, but we always know that it is an object. It is therefore safe to 
assign the result of `get()` to a variable of type `Object` or pass it as a parameter 
where the type `Object` is expected.

Answer (score 1):

I was explaining this item to my friend and specifically asked for the "safeAdd" method as a counter to the unsafeAdd example. So here it is.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();

    unsafeAdd(strings, new Integer(42)); // No compile time exceptions

    // New 
    safeAdd(strings, new Integer(42)); // Throwing an exception at compile time


    String s = strings.get(0); // Compiler-generated cast

}

private static void unsafeAdd(List list, Object o) {
    list.add(o);
}


private static <E> void safeAdd(List<E> list, E o) {
    list.add(o);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Let say,you are writing a common method to print the elements appearing in a List. Now, this method could be used for printing Lists of type Integer, Double,Object or any other type. Which one do you choose?

1. `List<Object>` : If we use this one, this would help us to print only the elements of type Object. It wont be useful for printing elements belonging to other classes like Double. This is because Generic does not support Inheritance by default and needs to be specified explicitely using 'super' keyword.

   ```
   // Would only print objects of type 'Object'

   public static void printList(List<Object> list) {
       for (Object elem : list)
           System.out.println(elem + " ");
       System.out.println();
   }
   ```
2. `List<?>` : This could help us have a common method for printing any datatype. We could use this method for printing instances of any type.

   ```
   //  The type would really depend on what is being passed
   public static void printList(List<?> list) {
       for (Object elem: list)
           System.out.print(elem + " ");
       System.out.println();
   }
   ```