# Generic types : wildcards vs variables of raw types

Tags: java, oop, generic-collections

Consider following methods:

```
public static void listAll(LinkedList list) {

    for(Object obj : list)
        System.out.println(obj);

}
```

and

```
public static void listAll(LinkedList<?> list) {

    for(Object obj : list)
        System.out.println(obj);

}
```

What is the difference between these two methods? If there is no difference, why we should use the second one?

Comment: And the difference is... wait, there's no difference!

Comment: no, i see. the second one uses wild cards but it didn't appear.

Comment: Use code tag and edit your question.

Comment: The first one is non-generic. Everything inside the list is `Object` which you need to cast. The second one is Generic. The type will be checked at compile time.

Comment: thank you for your help, i didn't know how to do that. :-)

Comment: Look at this [Raw types vs Unbounded Wildcards](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7360594/whats-the-difference-between-raw-types-unbounded-wild-cards-and-using-object-i)

Comment: Why down vote? there is a difference between both. See my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`<?>` doesn't allow you to add objects in list. See the program below. It is specific type of list we have passed to method `<?>`. 
Specific means, list was created with specific type and passed to `<?>` method `listAll`. Don't confuse with **word** `specific`. 
Specific can be any normal object, like, Dog, Tiger, String, Object, HashMap, File, Integer, Long.... and the list is endless.
`JLS` forces `<?>` method for **not to** perform **add** any `irrelevant objects` in called `<?>` method once you have defined *(defined in calling method not in `called-listAll` )* list containing `specific type` of object. 

It is like `<?>` saying **"don't touch me".**

```
public static void listAll(LinkedList list) 
{
    list.add(new String());  //works fine
    for(Object obj : list)
            System.out.println(obj);

}
public static void listAll(LinkedList<?> list) 
{
     list.add(new String());  //compile time error. Only 'null' is allowed.
     for(Object obj : list)
          System.out.println(obj);
}
```

Now let's look at the different scenario. What will happen when we declare specific type like, Dog, Tiger, Object, String ..... anything. Let's change the method to `specific type`.

```
public static void listAll(LinkedList<String> list)// It is now specific type, 'String'
{
    list.add(new String());//works fine. Compile time it knows that 'list' has 'String'
    for(Object obj : list)
         System.out.println(obj);
}
```

Comment: <?> does not allow to set objects in list, but we can get objects right? what's the type of objects we get (in a getter() method? is it object or type parameter bounds?

Comment: It is Object type always. Generic is all for convenience. It takes care of programmar not to mislead the coding. Otherwise programmer will find mess in run-time.

Comment: @CenaPi You should look up the "PECS" mechanism as described by Joshua Bloch in "Effective Java". "Producer Extends, Consumer Super". A wildcard <?> is synonymous to <? extends Object>, so "extends", thus a "producer". A "producer" means you can get things out of the list, but not add to it.

Comment: @SinaBarghidarian In that case you can add any `Foo` object. `((List<? super Foo>) new LinkedList<>()).add(new Foo());`

Answer (score 1):

`List` is a raw type, `List<?>` is a generic type with wildcard argument.

Suppose that we have the following variables:

```
List<?> a;
List<String> b;
List c;
```

The assignment `b=a` gives a compile-time error (a `List<String>` is not assignable to `List<?`), but `c=a` compiles fine (`List<String>` is assignable to the raw type `List` for compatibility with legacy code not using generics).

The assignment `b=c` gives a compile-time warning (`List<?>` is  not assignable to  `List<String>`), but `a=c` compiles fine (`List<String>` is assignable to `List<?>`)

Comment: help! i need more explanation