# Illegal generic type for instanceof for Collection<String>

Tags: java, collections

I have a `Map<String,Object>` and I iterate over its entry set and check the instance of `entry.getValue()`. I have two conditions to check, when `Object` is `String`/`Collection<String>`
Like this

```
Map<String, Object>inputMap; // accepted from a 3rd party call
if(MapUtils.isNotEmpty(inputMap)) {
     for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry :inputMap.entrySet()) {
                if (entry.getValue() instanceof String) {
                    
                } else if (entry.getValue() instanceof Collection<?>) {
                    
                }

            }
        }
```

Right now I am using `Collection<?>`. I want to use `Collection<String>` but when I do, I get this error

```
Illegal generic type for instanceof
```

As far as I have understood `Collection<?>` means `Collection` of anything
I have 2 questions:

1. if I continue using `Collection<?>` will there be any issue?
2. How can I use `Collection<String>` instead of `Collection<?>`

Comment: What is the problem to use ```else if (entry.getValue() instanceof Collection)```? Any errors?

Comment: Why do you have 2 loops? (entry.getValue() instanceof Collection) Should not give any compile time error. In fact compilation should fail because you have duplicate 'entry' variable.

Comment: @bluelurker, sorry that was mistake , typo mistake, i have edited the question now

Comment: @GeorgeLvov , yes ```Collection``` works !!! Thanks, Could you explain what is the difference between Collection<?> and Collection and Collection<Object>??

Comment: For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18928216/difference-between-raw-types-and-in-generics or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7360594/whats-the-difference-between-raw-types-unbounded-wild-cards-and-using-object-i

Comment: A great example why proper formatting matters. When you write `Collection<String>` without formatting it as code, the `<String>` will not be shown on Stackoverflow (because it looks like an HTML tag). Of course, that’s bad for a question about Generics.

Comment: @GeorgeLvov Based on the links you provided above```Collection``` alone can lead to unsafe operations. What is if i want to specify explicitly Collection<String>, is there a way? If No, what else can i try?