# Return a Class instance with its generic type

Tags: java, generics, type-erasure, generic-type-argument

Here's a simple example that demonstrates a type-erasure-related issue I am running into. I have a class like this:

```
public abstract class AbstractHandler<T> {

    ...
    public abstract Class<T> handledType();
}
```

Then I have this implementation:

```
public class ConcreteHandler extends AbstractHandler<Map<String, List<Thing>>> {

    @Override
    public Class<Map<String, List<Thing>>> handledType() {
        //what do I return here?!
    }
}
```

I can't return `Map<String, List<Thing>>.class`, since that's not even valid syntactically. I tried making the generic type-parameter in the subtype to be `HashMap<String, List<Thing>>` and then returning `new HashMap<String, List<Thing>>().getClass()`, but that doesn't work because the return type of `Class<T>#getClass()` is `Class<? extends T>`. I looked at [`TypeToken`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken.html) from Guava, and the `getRawType` method seemed promising, but it returns `Class<? super T>`.

I have a workaround for the time being that looks like this:

```
public class ThingListMap {
    private Map<String, List<Thing>> thingListMap;

    ...
}
```

and I just use `ThingListMap` as the generic type-parameter.

Another possible workaround is to perform a forced cast:

```
public Class<Map<String, List<Thing>>> handledType() {
    return (Class<Map<String, List<Thing>>>) new HashMap<String, List<Thing>>().getClass();
}
```

Is there a more-elegant way to do this?

**EDIT:** In response to one of the answers, I cannot change the signature of the `handledType` method since I do not own or control its source.

Comment: Need more info on what's the purpose of that method

Comment: *Is there any way to do this?"* In plain Java, no.

Comment: @eduyayo This is more of a conceptual question. I do have a workaround, but I wanted to see if there was a more elegant way.

Comment: @MaxZoom No, that won't work; the return type is `Class<T>`.

Comment: I had kind-of a thing lkike that and we added a factory mwthod for creating inatances of the templated but never to return the class.

Comment: The thing you'll be returning will be `Map.class`, regardless of what actual type you cast that too; there's no way around that.  (Except if you do the `new HashMap<Foo, Bar>().getClass()`, in which case it will be `HashMap.class`, cast to some other type, but the _actual object_ will still be a raw class type.)

Comment: Your class is not well conceived.  Instances of class `java.lang.Class` represent classes (duh), but you are trying to use one to represent a *type*, which is something more general.  Java does have a `Type` class for this concept, but it probably won't serve your purposes either.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I completely agree, but I didn't design this class and so I cannot change it. :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For some reason, Java doesn't allow you to cast `Map.class` directly to `Class<Map<String, List<Thing>>>`.  It's an unchecked cast anyway.

But it's legal to cast it twice, first to `Class<?>`, then to `Class<Map<String, List<Thing>>>`.

```
return (Class<Map<String, List<Thing>>>) (Class<?>) Map.class;
```

Being an unchecked cast, you may want to add `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`.

Comment: @eduyayo I don't understand your comment or how it applies to this answer.

Comment: *"For some reason [...]"* Basically the same reason you can't cast a `List<Cat>` to a `List<Dog>`. Neither is a supertype or subtype of the other. See also [*"Cannot convert from List<List> to List<List<?>>"*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26766704/2891664). RE: this answer here, casting is fine for something like object creation but note that it's the case that e.g. `Class<Map<String, String>>` will `==` a `Class<Map<Integer, Integer>>`.

Comment: This is a better (subjective, I guess :p) variation of my forcible cast of an ad-hoc `HashMap<K, V>` instance's class. I like the fact that I don't have to create that ad-hoc instance.

Comment: @Radiodef Yes, that's the reason.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @VivinPaliath Also, this is closer to the real type, as you are returning `HashMap.class` rather than `Map.class`.

Answer (score 4):

Guava's approach to this is to use [`TypeToken`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken.html)s. Your class would become

```
public abstract class AbstractHandler<T> {
    public TypeToken<T> handledType();
}

public class ConcreteHandler extends AbstractHandler<Map<String, List<Thing>>> {
    @Override
    public TypeToken<Map<String, List<Thing>>> handledType() {
        return new TypeToken<Map<String, List<Thing>>>() {};
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that would be ideal. Unfortunately I cannot change the signature of `handledType` in `AbstractHandler<T>`. I will mention that in the question.