# java.lang.Class generics and wildcards

Tags: java, generics, bounded-wildcard

Why is is that the following code does not compile?

```
interface Iface<T> { }

class Impl<T> implements Iface<T> { }

class TestCase {
    static Class<? extends Iface<?>> clazz = Impl.class;
}
```

The error is

> java: incompatible types: `java.lang.Class<Impl>` cannot be converted to `java.lang.Class<? extends Iface<?>>`

but I don't see why the wildcard doesn't capture.

Comment: Also see [*"Cannot convert from List<List> to List<List<?>>"*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26766704/2891664) for an extended explanation. (You're trying to convert a `Class<Impl>` to a `Class<? extends Iface<?>>` so essentially the same rules apply.) If you really need this then it should be fine to cast it in the way I've described over there. `(Class<? extends Iface<?>>)(Class<? extends Impl>)Impl.class` Otherwise, avoid raw type arguments.

Comment: @Radiodef Thanks for that link!  Sadly a cast doesn't work for annotation parameters, which is the real life use case that inspired this question.

Comment: Ouch. I'm not sure what to suggest then. You could change your annotation to `Class<? extends Iface>` but it's eh. Depends on what you're using the Class for. You could annotate it that way and kludge cast it later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The subtyping relationship here is:

```
          Class<? extends Iface>
           ╱                  ╲
Class<? extends Iface<?>>   Class<Impl>
```

(Which I explained in my answer to [*'Cannot convert from `List<List>` to `List<List<?>>`'*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26766704/2891664).)

So essentially it doesn't compile because it's a sideways conversion.

If it's possible, you can do the casting I described over there:

```
(Class<? extends Iface<?>>)(Class<? extends Impl>)Impl.class
```

If you can't do the cast, then you probably just have to deal with a raw bounded `Class<? extends Iface>`. It's annoying primarily because of the warnings but it opens up the possibility for an error:

```
interface Iface<T> {
    void accept(T a);
}

class Impl2 implements Iface<String> {
    public void accept(String a) { }
}

class TestCase {
    static Class<? extends Iface> clazz = Impl2.class;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // throws ClassCastException
        clazz.newInstance().accept(new Object());
    }
}
```

Unlikely to happen, but it depends on what you're doing I suppose.

---

I tend to think this is a problem with the Java type system.

- Possibly there should be a special rule that a type argument `? extends T<?>` contains a type argument `? extends T` such that e.g. a `Class<? extends T>` converts to a `Class<? extends T<?>>`.  This doesn't make sense from the perspective of the existing way that subtyping is defined (`T` is a supertype of `T<?>`) but it makes sense from the perspective of type safety.
- Or e.g. `List.class` should be a `Class<List<?>>` instead of a `Class<List>`.
- Or some other clever thing people smarter than me can think up.

The interesting thing about the `ClassCastException` I described above is that it's completely artificial. And in fact, preventing it with the unchecked cast causes a warning.

Just a sign that generics in Java are not done yet, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Because of [type-erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), when you say `Impl.class` you get a `Class<Impl>`. That is, you can say

```
Class<Impl> clazz = Impl.class;
```

Generics are a compile time type-safety feature.

Comment: But other similar constructs like `Class<? extends CharSequence> clazz = String.class` work.  It also works when I write `class Impl implements Iface<String> { }`, or `Class<? extends Iface> clazz`.

Comment: @TavianBarnes The key is that `String` does not take any generic arguments - as you point out, if `Impl` doesn't have any generic arguments it also works fine. (Note that both these classes *inherit* from other classes that do have generic parameters, that is ok - it is if the class has a generic parameter *itself* that presents the a difficulty to the compiler (because of type erasure.)

Comment: @berry120 Ah okay it makes sense to me now.  The raw type `Impl` in `Class<Impl>` causes all types in the hierarchy of `Impl` to be erased, so we effectively have `Impl extends Iface` but not `Impl extends Iface<?>` for any `?`.  Thanks!