# Dynamically return with the type of calling class using generics in Java

Tags: java, generics, this

Consider the following classes.

```
public class ClassA {

    public ArrayList<String> v1 = new ArrayList<>();

    public ClassA addOnce(String s1) {
        v1.add(s1);
        return this;
    }

}


public class ClassB extends ClassA {

    public ClassB addTwice(String s2) {
        v1.add(s2);
        v1.add(s2);
        return this;
    }

}
```

Now, it is possible to perform series of operations on `ClassA` as below

`new ClassA.addOnce("1").addOnce("2");`

but still one can not achieve the same on `ClassB` since `new ClassB().addOnce("1").addTwice("2");` is invalid as the `addOnce()` method returns the super class type and one has to cast down to ClassB again to use the `addTwice()` method. I tried to solve this using generics in the `addOnce()` method.

New Implementation of addOnce:

```
public<R extends ClassA> R addOnce(String s1) {
    v1.add(s1);
    return (R)this;
}
```

But still the compiler asks for a cast as it can not find the return type just based on the next method call since the method may be available to multiple classes (`addOnce()` is available to both `ClassA` and `ClassB`) and the return type won't converge. Is there a way to return `this` with the type of the calling class, typically when a subclass calls a parent class method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to do this, but I don't recommend either.

### Approach one: generics

Specifically, recursive ones (that refer back to the generic class itself):

```
public class ClassA<R extends ClassA<R>> { // note the recursive nature
    public ArrayList<String> v1 = new ArrayList<>();

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    protected R self() {
      return (R) this;
    }

    public R addOnce(String s1) {
        v1.add(s1);
        return self();
    }
}
```

If you don't like that SuppressWarnings (and you shouldn't! they can hide bugs), you can get around this by making an `abstract class AbstractClassA`, with a `protected abstract R self()` every subclass overrides:

```
// AbstractClassA looks like ClassA above; it contains addOnce
class ClassA extends AbstractClassA<ClassA> {
    @Override
    public ClassA self() {
        return this;
    }
}

class ClassB extends AbstractClassA<ClassB> {
    ClassB addTwice(String s2) {
        ...
        return this;
    }
}
```

That does mean that most of your use cases will use a wildcarded `AbstractClassA<?>` type. Besides that ugliness, this gets hairy if you try to serialize these instances. `AbstractClassA.class` returns a `Class<AbstractClassA>`, *not* a `Class<AbstractClassA<?>>`, which can [force you to do more unchecked casts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30385594/why-cant-i-cast-a-collectiongenericfoo-to-a-collectiongenericfoo).

Also, subclasses of AbstractClassA *don't* inherit that `<R>` type, so if you want to define new methods that keep the pattern (in ClassB, for instance), you'll have to repeat the pattern with a new generic parameter in each one. My prediction is that you'll regret it.

### Approach two: override each method

The other way is to manually override all of the methods in the base class. When you override a method, you [can have it return a subclass of the original method's return type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882584/what-is-a-covariant-return-type). So:

```
public class ClassA {

    public ArrayList<String> v1 = new ArrayList<>();

    public ClassA addOnce(String s1) {
        v1.add(s1);
        return this;
    }

}
public class ClassB extends ClassA {

    public ClassB addOnce(String s2) {
        super.addOnce(s2);
        return this; // same reference as in the super method, but now typed to ClassB
    }
    ...

}
```

This method doesn't have any hidden gotchas, like the first approach does. It works just like you think it would. It's just a pain, and it means that every time you add a method to ClassA, you have to add that method to ClassB (and ClassC, etc) as well, if you want things to keep working. If you don't have control over ClassB/C/etc (for instance, if you're publishing an API), then that could present a problem, and make your API feel half-baked.

### Approach three: Chain from more-specific subclasses first

This one isn't really an answer to your question, but rather a pattern that gets at the same problem. The idea is to keep ClassA and ClassB just as you have them, but always call ClassB's methods first:

```
new ClassB().addTwice("2").addOnce("1");
```

This approach works fine, but it's a bit awkward. Most of the time, people think in terms of first setting things on the base class, and then setting subclass-specific things on subclasses. If you you're okay with reversing that, and you really want these chained methods, this is probably the approach I would pick. But my real suggestion is:

### My suggestion: forget it

Java just doesn't handle these kinds of method chains well. I would suggest you just forget the whole thing, and don't try to fight the language on this point. Make the methods return `void` and put each call on its own line. Having worked with code that's tried the first and third approaches, I found the ugliness around it gets old really quickly, and is generally more of a pain than it's worth. (I've never seen the second approach works, because it's such a pain off the bat that nobody wants to even try it. :) )

Comment: I get the override approach but I still don't understand your approach 1. Still, `new ClassB().addOnce("1").addTwice("2")` won't work with Approach 1. Am I missing something? BTW, I too won't be writing/suggest to write such code but just wonder the possibility of achieving this.

Comment: Oh sorry, I have a typo there. `addOnce` should return `R`, _not_ `ClassA`. I'll fix that.

Comment: Yeah, I guessed the typo and the fixed one (with return type as R) even won't work.

Comment: Works on my machine (though I had to add `v1`, which I forgot to copy from your example). Unfortunately, I have to head out for the evening, so I can't make further edits for a while. Good luck!

Comment: Approach 1 works! I forgot to do `class ClassB extends ClassA<ClassB>` And thanks for not adding that in your answer only for which now I explored and understood how it works :)

Comment: You should note that approach 1a has an unchecked cast warning because it is *actually unsafe* -- with `class ClassB extends ClassA<ClassB>` you can then have `class ClassC extends ClassA<ClassB>`, which compiles without warnings or errors, but `new ClassC().addOnce().addTwice()` throws a class cast exception at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

To make Type Inference work, you need to declare generic parameter in `ClassA`. `ClassA` should look like below:

```
public class ClassA<T extends ClassA<T>> {
  public ArrayList<String> v1 = new ArrayList<>();

  public T addOnce(String s1) {
    v1.add(s1);
    return (T) this;
  }
}
```

Read more about [Type Inference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html)

Answer (score 1):

This question reminds me of method `overridding`.

```
class A {

    protected List<String> list = new LinkedList<>();

    public A addOnce(String s) {
        list.add(s);
        return this;
    }
}

class B extends A {

    public B addOnce(String s) {
        return (B) super.addOnce(s);
    }

    public B addTwice(String s) {
        super.addOnce(s);
        super.addOnce(s);
        return this;
    }
}
```

Why should class `A` even know class `B` exists. It is `B`'s responsibility. In this solution, class `B` delegates the functionality of adding once to its super class method but type casting is performed by `B` after it has the returned value. Use of generics is really not required in the current use case.