# Casting generic class is warning in eclipse but error in javac

Tags: java, eclipse, javac

I'm seeing a major difference in behavior between Eclipse and javac for the following code:

```
public class TestIncompatibleTypes {

    private static <V> void libraryMethod(Class<? extends List<V>> in) {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Eclipse warns about 'Unchecked cast'
        // Maven fails with 'incompatible types'
        Class<? extends List<String>> l = (Class<? extends List<String>>) ArrayList.class;
        libraryMethod(l);
    }
}
```

Eclipse issues an 'unchecked cast' warning for the above code, but it successfully compiles. Javac generates an error:

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_72-internal"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_72-internal-b15)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.72-b15, mixed mode)
$ javac -version
javac 1.8.0_72-internal
$ javac -source 8 TestIncompatibleTypes.java
TestIncompatibleTypes.java:13: error: incompatible types: Class<ArrayList> cannot be converted to Class<? extends List<String>>
        Class<? extends List<String>> l = (Class<? extends List<String>>) ArrayList.class;
                                                                                   ^
1 error
```

Can anyone explain why javac disallows the cast? My understanding is that they should be completely equivalent after type erasure.

Is there a workaround to get this to compile on both compilers?

Comment: As long as you're using unchecked casting anyway, what about `Class<? extends List<String>> l = (Class) ArrayList.class;` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a workaround to get this to compile on both compilers?

```
Class<? extends List<String>> clazz;
// casting to interim type
clazz = (Class<? extends List<String>>) (Class<? extends List>) ArrayList.class;
// raw types .......
clazz = (Class) ArrayList.class;
```

HOWEVER! This code deserves an explanation of why it works and when it might not be safe:

- `java.util.ArrayList` has no particular constraints for its type variable.
- `java.lang.Class` is immutable and can only be used to create new instances.

If you use different types besides `ArrayList` and `Class`, this same casting can cause heap pollution by e.g. casting away important information:

```
class IntegerList extends ArrayList<Integer> {}
// now we can create a new instance and put String in a List<Integer>
Class<? extends List<String>> clazz =
    (Class<? extends List<String>>) (Class<? extends List>) IntegerList.class;
```

(I'm also going to make the caveat that it could still be possible to cause heap pollution using `ArrayList.class` and I just haven't thought hard enough about it.)

In Java 8, we should prefer lambdas to reflection for instance creation, which avoids this entire problem:

```
static <V> void libraryMethod(Supplier<? extends List<V>> in) {}
void somewhere() {
    Supplier<? extends List<String>> supplier = ArrayList::new;
    libraryMethod(supplier);
}
```

Of course if you can't use this for some reason, then you are a little stuck doing the occasional kludgy thing with `Class`.

> Can anyone explain why javac disallows the cast?

Java doesn't allow "sideways" casts, e.g.:

```
Number n = ...;
String s = (Number) n; // compiler error
```

I explained how this works for the raw type argument [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30090242/2891664) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26766704/2891664).

The short explanation is that there is a subtyping relationship like this:

```
           Class<? extends List>
            ╱                 ╲
Class<? extends List<String>>  Class<ArrayList>
```

Both are subtypes of `Class<? extends List>` and neither one is a subtype nor a supertype of the other.

Comment: Excellent response. Your subtyping tree makes the reason for the error quite clear, although the prohibition against sideways casting seems odd considering that a cast is something inherently risky (at least from the compiler's perspective).

Comment: Sideways casts don't compile for non-generic types because you can determine that the cast will always fail (except for `null`). It's true that this is not always the case for generic types.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're casting a `Class<ArrayList>>` to `Class<? extends List<String>>`, but the `ArrayList` class doesn't have that kind of generic. I'm not sure if you need the `<String>` generic for your `Class<? extends List>`

Comment: @JoopEggen Try that and see if it works. It would work for `libraryMethod(Class<? extends List>)` but it does not work for `libraryMethod(Class<? extends List<V>>)`