# Method is not applicable for arguments when adding wildcard

Tags: java, generics, compiler-errors

I have following two classes:

```
class ProblematicConverter implements Converter<List<?>> {};
class NonProblematicConverter implements Converter<List> {};
```

And method of class Utils:

```
<T> void addConverter(Class<? extends T> cls, Converter<T> converter);
```

Now, first function invocation is ok but second produces error:

```
addConverter(List.class, new ProblematicConverter());
addConverter(List.class, new NonProblematicConverter());
```

Error says:

"The method addConverter(Class, Converter) in the type Utils is not applicable for the arguments (Class, ProblematicConverter)"

I do not understand why it's like that.

Comment: `List` isn't a subtype of `List<?>`. (It's actually the other way.) What are you trying to do here? It seems unlikely to me that you'll get this working as-is. You need to use something like Guava `TypeToken` or else really loosen up the declaration of `addConverter`.

Comment: `List` is a [raw type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html) and ? is a [wildcard](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html), And you should avoid using either of these unless you know EXACTLY what you're doing. (prefer `<T extends SpecificClass>` where you can)

Comment: @Radiodef function addConverter is provided by third party library I can not change it. I have to Implement class that implements Converter. Everything is fine when I use NonProblematicImplementation but I get compiler warning about raw List type. So I started to correct warrnings in my code.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment, I think the right thing to do here might be to use an unchecked cast on `List.class`, but first, the reason the code in the question doesn't compile is roughly:

- `T` of `addConverter` is inferred to be `List<?>`.
- The bounded wildcard in `cls` requires that its type argument be `T` or a subtype of `T`, but the raw type `List` is a supertype of `List<?>` ([specified here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.2)).
- Therefore, `Class<List>` is incompatible with the inferred type of `cls` which is `Class<? extends List<?>>`.

So, for example, either of the following two declarations would compile with the invocations in the question:

```
<T> void m(Class<T> cls, Converter<? extends T> converter) {}
<T> void m(Class<? super T> cls, Converter<T> converter) {}
```

That of course doesn't help you out, but it illustrates the relationship between `List` and `List<?>`.

You might see also [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26768390/2891664) two [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30091990/2891664) of mine which discuss similar situations.

So anyway, based on your comment saying that you're trying to eliminate raw types and can't change the declaration of `addConverter`, what could be appropriate is to use an unchecked cast from `Class<List>` to `Class<List<?>>`:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
static final Class<List<?>> WILD_LIST =
    (Class<List<?>>) (Class<? super List<?>>) List.class;
```

This will let you call e.g.:

```
addConverter(WILD_LIST, new ProblematicConverter());
```

However, I'd like to point out that unchecked casting is not a *general* solution. It's a solution to this specific problem of converting e.g. a `Class<GenericType>` to a `Class<GenericType<?>>`. It's safe to do because `GenericType<?>` is a more restrictive type than the raw type `GenericType` and because `Class` has a very limited range of things it can do with its type argument.

If you could change the declaration of `addConverter`, I think I would recommend using something like Guava `TypeToken` instead of `Class`, because then you don't have this sort of problem.

Comment: Small correction list.getClass() returns variable of type Class<? extends List>