# Typed vs. Non-typed ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

What's the difference between using a typed vs. non-typed`ArrayList` in Java?

For example, Using an `ArrayList` of `CustomObject`:

Typed:

```
ArrayList<CustomObject> typedArray = new ArrayList<>();
typedArray.add(new CustomObject);
```

or non-typed:

```
ArrayList<> nonTypedArray = new ArrayList<>();
nonTypedArray.add(new CustomObject);
```

Is there any situation where the latter is preferred? Is there any difference when the `ArrayList` is holding different datatypes, e.g. an ArrayList of `String`, `Int`, etc.?

Comment: Well it depends what you require.

Comment: @DarshanLila Please elaborate what you mean by require. I do only intend to perform sort functions etc.

Comment: If you require a `List` which strictly should contain same types you go for typed or otherwise. But generally the typed collections are preffered.

Comment: Very close to dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7360594/whats-the-difference-between-raw-types-unbounded-wild-cards-and-using-object-i; I suggest you give that a read.

Comment: `ArrayList<> nonTypedArray` is a compiler error. http://ideone.com/MZqmTP

Comment: Correct. It should have been`ArrayList nonTypedArray = new ArrayList();`. I did not edit it, since it would cause confusion when reading the answers. @Radiodef

Comment: It's already confusing. ; ) Anyway `ArrayList nonTypedArray = new ArrayList();` is called a raw type. http://stackoverflow.com/q/2770321/2891664 http://stackoverflow.com/tags/raw-types/info

Comment: Is a non-typed ArrayList a raw type? Would it make more sense to you if I asked the difference between a typed ArrayList, and a raw type ArrayList? @Radiodef

Comment: A type like `ArrayList` without a type parameter (the `<T>` part) is called a raw type. The difference between a raw type and a normal parameterized type is explain in the two links.

Comment: Then please elaborate what makes the question unclear, if you could find the answers for it in two other threads? @Radiodef

Comment: Before you replied to my comments, I had *no idea* what you were trying to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's never preferable to use the latter option. I don't think that is even possible. I think you meant:

```
 ArrayList nonTypedArray = new ArrayList();
```

This syntax is left over from Java 1.4 and earlier. It still compiles for the purposes of backwards compatibility.

Generics was introduced in Java 1.5 which allowed you to specify the types between angled brackets.

It is always preferable to use generics because it is more type-safe.

That is, if you specify

```
ArrayList<String> typedArray = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Then you cannot accidentally add an integer to this array list; if you tried to add an integer, the program would not compile.

Of course, Generics ensures type safety at compile time. At runtime     `ArrayList<String> typedArray = new ArrayList<String>();` becomes `ArrayList typedArray = new ArrayList();`. This is to maintain backwards compatibility.

Comment: *"I don't think that is even possible."* You're right, it's not. I suspect the OP saw a proper usage of the diamond like `ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<>();` and got confused.

Answer (score 4):

In the Second Approach, it is not mandatory to add only `CustomObject` whereas it is in 1st Approach, otherwise, you will get Compilation Error.

```
ArrayList<CustomObject> typedArray = new ArrayList<>();
typedArray.add(new CustomObject());
```

This approach is generally preferable as there are no chances of having Class Cast Exception but in second approach there are high chances of that !!

JavaDocs explains it beautifully : [Why to prefer Generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html)

1. Stronger type checks at compile time.
2. Elimination of casts.
3. Enabling programmers to implement generic algorithms.

Comment: *"In Second Approach , it is not mandatory to add only CustomObject"* This is completely made-up... You are speculating about non-existent syntax. The second approach is actually a compiler error. It doesn't mean *anything*.

Comment: @Radiodef , yes it is compilation error , but when i gave the answer the second approach was this `ArrayList nonTypedArray = new ArrayList();` not `ArrayList<> nonTypedArray = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: I did not make any edits to the question. But `ArrayList<> nonTypedArray = new ArrayList<>();` is a compile error, It should be `ArrayList nonTypedArray = new ArrayList();`. I did not edit my question since some of the answers addressed this, and it would cause confusion if I removed it from the question.

Answer (score 2):

> What's the difference between using a typed vs. non-typed ArrayList in
> Java?

A typed/generic ArrayList is a collection of objects in which the "type" of the object is defined in angled brackets. Generics were introduced in Java 5 to create type-safe collections.

Before Generics the collection was called untyped/raw type collection because there was no way to specify the compiler the type of the collection being created.

**The difference between both is to detect type-safe operations at compile time.**

In both of your cases, you are adding object(s) of type 'CustomObject' to the ArrayList. There will be no issue while adding elements in the list, as both lists will consider them as typed objects.

**Typed:**

```
ArrayList<CustomObject> typedArray = new ArrayList<CustomObject>();
typedArray.add(new CustomObject);
```

**Untyped:**

```
ArrayList<> nonTypedArray = new ArrayList<>();
nonTypedArray.add(new CustomObject);
```

> Is there any situation where the latter is preferred?

I don't think so. As generics are recommended to be used while creating a list to ensure type-safe operations.

> Is there any difference when the ArrayList is holding different
> datatypes, e.g. an ArrayList of String, Int, etc.?

Surely, there is a reasonable difference. For an untyped list, you will need to add type-cast while fetching elements from a list. As there is a possibility of the compiler throwing a ClassCastException at runtime due to different types of elements.

Answer (score 0):

In runtime, there is absolutely no difference, however in compilation time, using type parameters can save you from a plethora of errors, so it is always preferable to use generics properly.

The only case where raw types are used reasonably is in legacy applications, but even in this case, you try to use typed parameters if you can.

Answer (score 0):

The use of type simplifies your coding removing the need of casting and also stores your data efficiently
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I know this is an old post.  But I wanted to share an instance where an untyped ArrayList is useful: when you're writing a function that supposed to act on arbitrary element types.  For example, suppose you want to make a generic shuffle function that knows how to shuffle an array.  Like so:

```
ArrayList<Die> diceRolls = getGetPossibleDiceRolls();
ArrayList<Card> cardDeck = getPossibleCards();
ArrayList<GirlToDate> blackbook = getBlackbook();
shuffle(diceRolls);
shuffle(cardDeck);
shuffle(blackbook);

.
.
void shuffle(ArrayList array) {
    int size = array.size();
    for (int i=0; i<size; ++i) {
        int r = random.nextInt(size - i) + i;

        // Swap
        Object t = array.get(i);
        array.set(i, array.get(r));
        array.set(r, t);
    }    
}
```

Some might argue "yeah, but the proper way to do this is to create an interface or subclass of something like a Shuffleable type..."  But really?

Comment: *"Some might argue "yeah, but the proper way to do this is to create an interface or subclass of something like a Shuffleable type...""* The proper way would be a wildcard.

Answer (score 0):

In Java 1.7 and upwards you should normally use the constructor like this:

```
ArrayList<MyObject> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

or else for a more general `List` object:

```
List<MyObject> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Observe that you only specify the type `<MyObject>` once, not twice.  This makes your code easier to maintain.  The `<>` causes the constructor to return an `ArrayList` which is already typed to match the field/variable to which it is being assigned - so that no cast will be required in the calling code.

Do not use `new ArrayList()` as the constructor.  This returns an *untyped* `ArrayList` which then has to be cast to a type to match the field/variable to which it is being assigned.  This means unnecessary type checking and casting and so generally reduces performance.